# How can I download a file through my application

Tags: c#

Hai Guys.,

Im doing an Application titled Online Education. In my application i have to enable the trainees to download the pdf tutorials that i've been already stored in database.How can I do this process using C#.Net..,

Thanks in advance for those who answer this question....,

Shankar.

Comment: First, try asking the question in the proper format.
Second, I'm sure you can find many many examples of this using google. 
Thirdly, what web technology are you using?

Comment: How are you storing the "pdf tutorials" to the DB ? as a blob?

Answer (score 2):

So you are already putting your file in DB?

To allow users download file you should use [Response.BinaryWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524318.aspx). You will also need to send some special headers to user.

All in all the code looks like this:

```
  Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
  Response.AppendHeader( "content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name );
  Response.BinaryWrite(data);
  Response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass the file to the response stream with the appropriate content type set. Then the browser will open a dialog to save or open the document.

[File download using C#](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Code-Examples/File-download-using-C/)